# Cannot Optimize Elimination Game (Leetcode)

Tags: c, recursion

I was trying out this Leetcode problem today ([#390 - Elimination Game](https://leetcode.com/problems/elimination-game/description/)). I came up with a solution which seems to be in O(n.log(n))

The problem requires a program to remove alternating elements back and forth in continuous cycles and return the one element that is left

I cannot think of any further ways to optimize my code.

#### Source Code

The default function by Leetcode for this specific problem:

```c
int lastRemaining(int n){
    int numberarray[n];
    int* numberarraypointer = numberarray;
    for (int iterable = 0; iterable < n; iterable++){
        *(numberarray+iterable) = iterable + 1; // filling the array with arbitrary values
    }
    int result = recurse(numberarraypointer, n, 1);
    return result;
}
```

Recursive function that iterates itself back and forth alternatively, and removes required elements

```c
int recurse(int* numberarray, int arraysize, int accessmode){
    if (arraysize == 1){
        return *(numberarray);
    } else if (arraysize == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    
    if (accessmode == 1){
        for (int iterable = 0; iterable < arraysize; iterable++){
            remove_element(numberarray, arraysize, iterable);
            arraysize--;
        }
    } else {
        for (int iterable = arraysize-1; iterable >= 0; iterable -= 2){
            remove_element(numberarray, arraysize, iterable);
            arraysize--;
        }
    }
    
    return recurse(numberarray, arraysize, -accessmode);
}
```

Function to remove element (replacing by zero)

```c
void remove_element(int* arr, int size, int index) {
    if (index < 0 || index >= size) {
        return;
    }
    for (int i = index; i < size - 1; i++) {
        *(arr + i) = *(arr + i + 1);
    }
    *(arr + size - 1) = 0;
}
```

For `n = 3844` (during **Run**) I am getting a 18ms runtime, but for a `n = 3835` (during **Submit**) I am getting a *Time Limit Exceeded* message.

Comment: Constraints "1 <= n <= **10⁹**", `int numberarray[n];` I think that's game over right there (no, a 4 GB array is not a good idea), toss this solution and start over.

Comment: Think of which elements you remove! Any time you do so, the successor of the deleted element moves towards front (including all the following ones) and next you are going to delete is the sucessor's successor. So actually you are always deleting every second element. You could do this in just one single iteration – though by the nature of the problem I'd guess that there's a closed formula depending on `N` only giving you the index of the number finally remaining…

Comment: I have a strong feeling there is O(1) algo for this. Run it for few different N's and see if you spot a pattern.

Comment: I suspect that the solution is related to the binary decomposition of `n`. Therefore a O(log n) solution, fast enough.

Comment: This would be better asked on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: One pattern that I see like the result is always even, except for `n==1` (which is actually obvious, because only even numbers are remaining after the first step)

Comment: @EugeneSh. [Tried myself](https://godbolt.org/z/T3ETn3Wa3), just me being too dumb to spot that pattern ;(

Comment: It's definitely possible to do it in O(log n) time and O(1) space. I have done it.

Comment: @Aconcagua Tried this too, looks like I am too dumb as well :) Probably harder to spot than I imagined. Still should be some closed form solution... But that's just feeling.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a log(n) solution;
Iteratively, we divide by two the number of remaining values (i.e. `n` is divided by two) and we check
if the corresponding bit must be set to 0 or 1 in these remaining values.

I found more convenient to consider numbers from `0` to `n-1` and then add 1 to the last value.

```
#include "stdio.h"

int lastRemaining(int n) {
        if (n < 3) return n;
        int ascending = 1;
        int last = 0;
        int pow2 = 1;
        while (n > 2) {
            if (ascending) {
                last += pow2;
            } else {
                last += pow2 * (n % 2);
            }
            n = n / 2;
            pow2 *= 2;
            ascending = 1 - ascending;
        }
        if ((n == 2) && ascending) last += pow2;
        return last + 1;
    };

int main() {
    int n;
    scanf ("%d", &n);
    int last = lastRemaining (n);
    printf ("%d\n", last);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution is similar to @Damian's answer, so he should get the credit. I didn't want to post it due to spoilers, but damage has been done!

```
int lastRemaining(int n)
{
    int pass;
    int retval;
    int addon;

    if (n <= 0) {
        return n;
    }

    retval = 1;
    pass = 0;
    addon = 1;  /* 2**pass */
    while (n > 1) {
        if ((n & 1) != 0 || (pass & 1) == 0) {
            retval += addon;
        }
        pass++;
        addon <<= 1;
        n >>= 1;
    }
    return retval;
}


#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i;

    for (i = 1; i <= 200; i++) {
        printf("%d: %d\n", i, lastRemaining(i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```